# Rails 3 - Ruby running within JS if

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

Why is ruby code ran even if its within an jQuery if statement?

I'm working with a modal (twitter bootstrap) and setting a session when the modal is shown/hidden, the modal has this code:

```
$("#modal").on("shown", function () {
  <% session[:modal] = true %>
})

...

$("#modal").on("hidden", function () {
  <% session[:modal] = nil %>
})
```

What I want is to set the session when the modal is opened, so a method knows when its opened, and set it to nil, so the same method knows when its closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ruby code is being run on the server and javascript in the browser. So all ruby code executes before javascript.

Comment: Makes complete sense...any ideas how can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What are you using that `session[:modal]` for? Can you describe your purpose a bit more?

Comment: In a method:

if session[:modal]
#render partial
else
#launch modal and render partial
end

Comment: I think there's bigger issue related to whole approach. I wouldn't store any that kind of information in session. What if user has two tabs of the same page open?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the client modify something in the rails session, you'll need to send an ajax request to the server.

Another option might be to use session cookies instead of using the rails session.  Session cookies are great if you're just setting little bits of data inside the browser.  There's a few cookie plugins for jquery.  [Here's one](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) on github.  You could do something like this:

```
$("#modal").on("shown", function () {
  $.cookie('is_modal', '1');
})
```

Update: I just read your other comment.  If you're doing server logic based on that value, then yeah, you'll need to tell the server with an ajax call.